# AspectJ: intercept constructor in scala

Tags: scala, constructor, aspectj

I'm trying to intercept a constructor parameter in scala with aspectj:

```
class ConstructorTest extends FlatSpecLike with Matchers {

  "MyObjectAspect" should "work" in {

    val t = new MyObject("leon")

    val result = t.talk()

    result should be("LEON")

  }
}


class MyObject(text: String) {

  def talk(): String = {

    println(text)

    text

  }
}


@Aspect

class MyObjectAspect {

  @Around(value = "execution (com.leon.aop.MyObject.new(..))")

  def constructCP(jp: ProceedingJoinPoint): AnyRef = {

    try {

      println("Start...")

      val args = jp.getArgs

      args(0) = args(0).toString.toUpperCase

      jp.proceed(args)

    } finally {

      println("End...")

    }

  }

}
```

It seems not work.

However, a very similar java version could work:

```
public class AopTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){

        MyJob t = new MyJob("leon");

        String result = t.talk();

        System.out.println(result);

        Assert.assertEquals(result, "LEON");

    }

}


public class MyJob {

    private String text;

    public MyJob(String value){
        text = value;
    }

    public String talk(){
        System.out.println(text);
        return text;
    }
}

@Aspect

public class MyJobAspect {

    @Around(value = "execution (com.leon.aop.MyJob.new(..))")

    public Object constructCP(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        try {

            System.out.println("Start..");

            Object[] args = jp.getArgs();

            args[0] = args[0].toString().toUpperCase();

            return jp.proceed(args);

        } finally {

            System.out.println("End...");
        }

    }

}
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Leon

Answer (score 0):

I think I told you before on the AspectJ mailing list: You need to bind arguments you want to modify via `args()`. Do what I told you on the ML and stop asking the same question everywhere. This is the second time already. Just ignoring my advice and asking again somewhere else does not solve your problem and just creates extra work and extra trouble for those willing to help you.